# How do I print a dictionary in alphabetical order that includes assigned values?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this Python Code:

```
def dictofvalues():
    values = {'A': '1', 'C': '3', 'B': '2'}
    return(values)

def main():
    values = dictofvalues()
    print(sorted(values))
```

Which prints: A, B, C.

However, I want it to print A:1, B:2, C:3. 
In other words, I want it to print the item with the assigned value as well.

How does one go about doing this?

Comment: If you want it to be sorted on the keys, the easiest/most straightforward way is just to create a for loop: `for key in sorted(values): print("{}: {}".format(key, values[key]))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: Genius. Works perfectly. Thanks a lot for that one :)

Comment: Perhaps equally genius would have been simply searching. It's one of the most answered answers out there.

Answer (score 0):

Simply print out the dictionary as a list of tuples:

```
def dictofvalues():
    values = {'A': '1', 'C': '3', 'B': '2'}
    return(values)

def main():
    values = dictofvalues().items()
    print(sorted(values))
```

Comment: Also works perfectly, no issues here. Thanks for this method, a special thanks for the actual code! :D

Comment: @InvestigativeMoth no problem, feel free to accept this answer by clicking the green check to give both of us reputation and inform the community that you have found a satisfactory answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use OrderedDict from module collections:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def dictofvalues():
    values = {'A': '1', 'C': '3', 'B': '2'}
    return(values)

def main():
    values = dictofvalues()
    print(OrderedDict(sorted(d.items())))
```

I hope it helps,